# Set compiler name in the Makefile

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile, icc

I have a Makefile suppose to compile my app in multiple host, some of them has built in intel compiler (icpc) and others just have g++. I would like that makefile automatically detect availability of icpc and if it is available, compile application with intel compiler, otherwise just compile it with g++.

How do I have to change Makefile to automatically detect availability of icpc compiler ?

Here is my try which simply did not work

```
ERR = $(shell icpc 2>/dev/null ; echo $? )
ifeq "$(ERR)" "127"
    CXX = g++
else
    CXX = icpc
endif
```

Comment: What are the values of `ERR` on the two systems?

Comment: on the one with icpc is 4, on the other system without icpc is 127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for detecting `icpc` instead. Also better check against `0` instead of `127`, since there may be differences from one system to another

```
ERR = $(shell which icpc >/dev/null; echo $$?)
ifeq "$(ERR)" "0"
    CXX = icpc
else
    CXX = g++
endif

all:
    echo $(CXX)
```

Comment: It does not work,$(ERR) holds nothing (not even 0). The assignment to ERR does not work in Makefile.

Comment: @ARH You're right, I forgot to double the `$` sign in `echo $?`. Fixed.